# Is my proof correct for showing $X \times Y$ Lindelöf if $X$ is Lindelöf and $Y$ is compact?

Tags: general-topology

This is from an exercise of Munkres, Topology.

I'm trying to prove $X$ Lindelöf and $Y$ compact implies $X \times Y$ Lindelöf.

This was my attempt:

Suppose $\mathcal{A}$ is an open cover of $X \times Y$. Denote the elements as $A_\alpha$.

Then, the collection of all $\pi_2(A_\alpha)$ is an open cover of $Y$. Since $Y$ is compact, it has a finite subcollection that covers $Y$.

Same for the collection of all $\pi_1(A_\alpha)$, is an open cover of $X$ which is Lindelöf thus has a countable subcollection that covers $X$.

($\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ are projection maps to $X$ and $Y$ respectively.)

Our desired countable collection of $\mathcal{A}$ is of those $A_\alpha$ such that $\pi_i(A_\alpha)$ is in the finite/countalble subcollections above. End of proof.

I feel something isn't quite right about my proof, but I can't pinpoint it. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Your proof would also show that the product of two Lindelöf spaces is Lindelöf, which is false.